# Matlab question about finding the absolute maximum value of a function between a given interval

Tags: matlab, octave

lets say i have a function f=@(x) -1/x^2. I need to find the maximum value between [1,2].
so the answer is 1 since if x=1 the maximum value of abs(-1/x^2)

is there an matlab/octave built in feature that takes a function, the interval and return a number?

Comment: `fminsearch` maybe

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is an instance of a nonlinear-programming problem.

In base octave, you can use the `sqp` function for this:
https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Nonlinear-Programming.html#Nonlinear-Programming

Example:

```
f = @(x) -1 ./ (x .^ 2);

Min = sqp( 1.5,    % Initial guess. I chose middle of proposed range
             f,    % The function to be minimized
            [],    % Function representing equality constraint. Not used here.
            [],    % Function representing inequality constraint. Not used here.
             1,    % Lower bound of 1 for x
             2     % Upper bound of 2 for x
         )

% output: Min = 1
```

Alternatively there's also `fmincon` from the optim package/toolbox (in [octave](https://octave.sourceforge.io/optim/function/fmincon.html)/[matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) respectively) which works similarly. If you're after octave/matlab intercombatibility specifically, this may be a better choice.